# Chat Client not Connecting to Server

Tags: java

I am working on a simple Java chat server. I have the server completed and now I'm trying to get my client to connect. So far its not connecting and giving errors on the server side I don't know a whole lot about network programming but the client is supposed to connect by typing `java <ChatClient> <IP> <Port>`, and that works it just looks like they are not talking correctly. I know the server works because I have been testing in TELNET. Does anyone have any suggestions?

**SERVER OUTPUT**

```
Server Started...
Connection reset
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:130)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:282)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:324)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:176)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:153)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:316)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:379)
at ChatServer$HandleClient.<init>(ChatServer.java:47)
at ChatServer.process(ChatServer.java:18)
at ChatServer.main(ChatServer.java:23)
```

**CHAT CLIENT**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.net.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import static java.lang.System.out;

public class  ChatClient {
PrintWriter output;
BufferedReader input;
Socket client;

public ChatClient(String ip, int port) throws Exception {
client = new Socket(ip,port);
input = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( client.getInputStream()) ) ;
    output = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(),true);
input.readLine();
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
    String ip= args[0];
    int port= Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        new ChatClient(ip,port);
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        out.println( "Error --> " + ex.getMessage());
    }

} // end of main

// inner class for Messages Thread
class  MessagesThread extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        String line;
        try {
            while(true) {
                line = input.readLine();

            } // end of while
        } catch(Exception ex) {}
    }
}
} //  end of client
```

**CHAT SERVER**

```
// Chat Server runs at port no. 9020
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.net.*;
import static java.lang.System.out;

public class  ChatServer {
  ArrayList<String> users = new ArrayList<String>();
  ArrayList<String> buffer = new ArrayList<String>();
  ArrayList<HandleClient> clients = new ArrayList<HandleClient>();
  Socket client;

  public void process() throws Exception  {
      ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(9020,10);
      out.println("Server Started...");
      while( true) {
         client = server.accept();
         HandleClient c = new HandleClient(client);
         clients.add(c);
     }  // end of while
  }
  public static void main(String ... args) throws Exception {
      new ChatServer().process();
  } // end of main

  public void bc(String user, String message)  {
        // send message to all connected users
        for ( HandleClient c : clients )
           if ( ! c.getUserName().equals(user) )
              c.sendMessage(user,message);
  }

  class  HandleClient extends Thread {
        String name = "";
    BufferedReader input;
    PrintWriter output;

    public HandleClient(Socket  client) throws Exception {
         // get input and output streams
     start();
     input = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( client.getInputStream())) ;
     output = new PrintWriter ( client.getOutputStream(),true);
     output.println("Welcome to Kimberly's Chat room");
     // receives the name of the client
     output.println("Enter your name: ");
     // read name of the client
     name  = input.readLine();
     users.add(name); // adds the name of the client to the vector
     output.println("Thanks for joining " + name + ". If you need help, type \"help\" for a list of commands.");
     //start();
        }

        public void sendMessage(String uname,String  msg)  {
        output.println(uname + ":" + msg);
    }

        public String getUserName() {
            return name;
        }

    public String toString() {
            return name;
        }

        public void run()  {
             String line;
         try    {
               while(true)   {
            line = input.readLine();
            String[] temp;
            temp = line.split(":");
                //checks different input from the client
            //checks to see if the client wants to terminate their connection
            //removes the client's name from the list
            if ("adios".equals(line)){
                output.println("Server closing connection...");
                clients.remove(this);
                users.remove(name);
                break;
                    }
            else if("get".equals(line)){
                output.println(buffer.toString());
            }
            else if("getNames".equals(line)){
                output.println(users.toString());
            }
            //checks to see if the client typed in help to receive a list of the commands
            else if("help".equals(line)){
                output.println("Here is a list of user commands:");
                output.println("adios: exit");
                output.println("get: receives a response of the entire chat buffer");
                output.println("help: lists the commands and their syntax");
                output.println("name: receives a response of \"OK\" and adds the name to a list");
            }
            else if("name".equals(temp[0])){
                users.add(temp[1]);
                output.println("OK");
            }
            else if("push".equals(temp[0])){
                buffer.add(name + ":" + temp[1]);
                output.println("OK");
            }
            else if("test".equals(temp[0])){
                output.println(temp[1].toString());
            }
            else{
                bc(name,line); // method  of outer class - send messages to all
            }
           } // end of while
         } // try
         catch(Exception e) {
           System.out.println(e.getMessage());
         }
         try{
        client.close();
         }
         catch(Exception e) {
           System.out.println(e.getMessage());
         }
        } // end of run()
   } // end of inner class

} // end of Server
```

Answer (score 0):

Your client code is mostly at fault: `main()` starts, connects, reads a single line of input from the server, then quits without ever writing any content to the server or asking the user to type in any input.

Your server should handle client termination more gracefully; the server is significantly harder to understand, but every place where you accept client input you should be prepared to handle an exception that indicates a client has disconnected without being polite enough to *ask* for a disconnect. (This happens all the time; machines reboot and routers die. Cell coverage goes dead...) When an exception is raised, your code should figure which client is responsible and remove them from the connected lists.